# how to set shadow to a View in android?

Tags: android, view, shadow

I want to know how to add a shadow layer to any general View in android.  for eg: suppose i have a layout xml, showing something like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    <Button....  
    ...  
</LinearLayout>
```

Now when it is displayed I want to have a shadow around it.

Comment: Similar Question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/52954743/9640177 - how to outline vector drawable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a simple trick, using two views that form the shadow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="#CC55CC">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0">
            <TableRow>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView  
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
                        android:text="@string/hello" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#55000000"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="#55000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It's better to use a gradient for the color.

Comment: using 9patch drawable backgroung is far more simple and the layout is much cleaner then

Comment: thanks @praveenb, however I think that the 9patch drawable background is the best solution

Comment: This is not the right way of doing in XML. It grows the depth of layout and may lead to slow rendering of UI in low end phones or even in high end ones.
The correct way always is to use a 9patch image. It is advised to make a cleaner and performance keen UI not just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 38):

The best way to create a shadow is to use a `9patch` image as the
background of the view (or a `ViewGroup` that wraps the view).

The first step is to create a png image with a shadow around it. I
used photoshop to create such an image. Its really simple.

- Create a new image with Photoshop.
- Add a layer and create a black square of 4x4.
- Create a shadow on the layer by selecting the layer in layer
  explorer and clicking on a button titled fx and choosing drop shadow.
- Export the image as png.

The next step is to create 9-patch drawables from this image.

- Open `draw9patch` from `android-sdk/tools`
- Open the image in `draw9patch`
- Create 4 black lines on the four sides of the square like the
  following and then save the image as `shadow.9.png`.

Now you can add this shadow as the background of the views you want to
add the shadow to. Add `shadow.9.png` to `res/drawables`. Now add it
as a background:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/shadow"
  android:paddingBottom="5px"
  android:paddingLeft="6px"
  android:paddingRight="5px"
  android:paddingTop="5px"
>
```

I recently wrote a [blog post](http://sapandiwakar.in/adding-shadows-to-views-in-android-using-9-patch-image/) that explains this in detail and
includes the 9patch image that I use for creating the shadow.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted answer. Also, the blog link is dead.

Comment: @ranjith From a terminal, run the draw9patch command from your SDK sdk/tools directory to launch the Draw 9-patch tool.

Comment: there is tool we can create 9 patch images online
http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Answer (score 13):

Assuming u would use a linear layout(i have considered a vertical linear layout)..and have a view just below your linear layout.Now for this view provide a start colour and end colour..
I also wanted to get this thing,its working for me..If you need a even better effect,then just work around the start and end colour.

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_back_bgn"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@+id/vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        >
    </View>


</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_back_bgn.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#FF4500" />

</shape>
```

**shadow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">    
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#4D4D4D"
        android:endColor="#E6E6E6"
        android:angle="270"
        >
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

I tried to post an image which i have it after using the above code,but stackoverflow doesnot allow me coz i dont have reputation..Sorry about that.

Comment: fwiw i think your reputation is mighty fine.  thanks for answering.

Answer (score 10):

You can use elevation, available since API level 21

> The elevation of a view, represented by the Z property, determines the
>   visual appearance of its shadow: views with higher Z values cast
>   larger, softer shadows. Views with higher Z values occlude views with
>   lower Z values; however, the Z value of a view does not affect the
>   view's size. To set the elevation of a view:
>
> in a layout definition, use the
>
> ```
> android:elevation
> ```
>
> attribute. To set the elevation of a view in the code of an activity,
>   use the
>
> ```
> View.setElevation()
> ```
>
> method.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

Comment: This solution only works if you are targeting api 21 (Lollipop) and higher.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my cheesy version of the solution...This is the modification of the solution found
[here](http://codebybrian.com/2013/05/05/adding_dropshadow_to_android_view.html)

I didn't like how the corners look so I faded all of them...

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--Layer 0-->
<!--Layer 1-->
<!--Layer 2-->
<!--Layer 3-->
<!--Layer 4 (content background)-->

<!-- dropshadow -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:centerColor="#10CCCCCC"
            android:angle="180"/>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:centerColor="#20CCCCCC"
            android:angle="180"/>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:centerColor="#30CCCCCC"
            android:angle="180"/>

        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:centerColor="#40CCCCCC"
            android:angle="180"/>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient 
            android:startColor="@color/white"
            android:endColor="@color/white"
            android:centerColor="#50CCCCCC"
            android:angle="180"/>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- content background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/PostIt_yellow" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Looks insanely bad on screen! And adding so many layers might be a rendering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create card_background.xml in the res/drawable folder with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then add the following code to the element to which you want the card layout

```
android:background="@drawable/card_background"
```

the following line defines the color of the shadow for the card

```
<solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
</LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@color/dropShadow" />
```

*Use Just Below the LinearLayout*

**Another Method**

[image]

create "rounded_corner_bg.xml" in /drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/primaryColor" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#F7F7F7" />

        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

*To use this Layout* `android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bg"`