# Inner shadow in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How i can set inner shadow on right side in `LinearLayout` ?

Like below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [part.lt](http://www.part.lt/img/de00b7d49da222d110c0b2c5fd23c7f3567.png))</sub>

Comment: take a similar nine patch image and set it as background of that linear layout

Comment: you can read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523936/how-to-get-shadow-on-android-linear-layout

Comment: maybe i can set shadow without picture? Because my app will be fitted to all size screens.

Comment: actually this is why i have suggested you to use nine patch image

Comment: you can also create shape drawable instad of creating nine patches. look at my answear below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can just use simple View with background which will be gradient.

this gradient could be a shape drawable eg

```
 <shape>
   <gradient android:startColor="#000000" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:angle="90"/>
 </shape>
```

you just need to set appropriate angle for your shadow.

Comment: Your `<shape>` declaration is missing `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0):

create a drawable file and use the view as background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#72CA5C54"
            android:centerColor="#43F71803"
            android:endColor="#272525"
            android:angle="45"/>

    </shape>
```