# How can I set shadows to Android views using 9-patch images

Tags: android, shadow, nine-patch

I am trying to set shadow in views in ma Android app. I have created shadow using 2 views but I am looking for an alternative way to do it better? Has anyone know how to do this?

Here is what I have tried:

```
            <TableRow>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView  
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
                        android:text="@string/this_is_text" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:background="#FFFEEE"/>
            </TableRow>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android

Comment: Are you trying to add shadow to a textview?