# How to create button shadow in android material design style

Tags: android, button, shadow, material-design

New material design guidelines introduce elevated buttons which are dropping nice shadow. According to the preview SDK documentation there will be `elevation` attribute available in new SDK. However, is there any way to achieve similar effect now?

[image]

Comment: This answer details how to do it with a 9 patch image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android/14196186#14196186

Comment: @milano Have you solved this yet? `setElevation` or `ViewCompat.setElevation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

Layout having **button**

```
<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_button_ripple_selector"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/button_text_selector"
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_elevation"/>
```

**drawble/button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"/>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button"/>

</selector>
```

**anim/button_elevation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="2dip"
            android:valueTo="4dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="4dip"
            android:valueTo="2dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

If you have a button in rectangular shape then you are done here. But if you have circular or oval shaped button then it would be looking like,

[image]

To remove **corners** from circular or oval shaped button add this code to your `.java` file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...........
    int buttonSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.button_size);
    Outline circularOutline = new Outline();
    circularOutline.setOval(0, 0, buttonSize, buttonSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUTTONS; i++) {
        Button button = ......
        .......
        button.setOutline(circularOutline);
        ........
    }
    .....
}
```

Angular shape removed!! Now, it would look exactly like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9-patch images, with shadows. Put the image in drawable--xxhdpi and set it as background on the button or other element.

```
android:background="@drawable/shadow_bg"
```

Comment: This will not create dynamic shadows that change on touch.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use CardView as a Button and use its CardView as a Button and its setCardElevation method.
Combined with touch events and ValueAnimator, you could get nice animated shadow below the button.