# shadow and line bottom action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want make action bar with shadow and line like this image

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTfbQ.png)

my main problem is drop shadow and line under action bar.

Comment: Creating a 9-patch with either the line and the drop shadow in it might help. See: [How to set shadow to a view (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14196186/1791820)

Answer (score 0):

As @pattaFeuFeu instruct create 9Patch images and use this code for set image in `ActionBar` in your activity

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_header_bar));
```