# How to add a shadow above a view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have a view that is to server as a footer title. It is just a view, that you may think of as a button or a textview or a layout (I am open to anything really). Here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <ScrollView >… </ScrollView> //match parent width and height
   <MyBottomView/> // align parent bottom
 </RelativeLayout>
```

So as you can see the ScrollView does scroll below MyBottomView. I want to add a top shadow to the MyBottomView so it looks more like Material Design. How might I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set shadow to a View in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are some solutions for this problem - choose your best:

- On StackOverflow, [in this post from 22 October 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005714/how-to-show-shadow-around-the-linearlayout-in-android), you would read:

> There is no such attribute in Android, to show a shadow. But possible ways to do it are:

> 1. Add a plain LinearLayout with grey color, over which add your actual layout, with margin at the bottom and right equal to 1 or 2 dp.

> 2. Have a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your Linear layout.

and

> There is also another solution to the problem by implementing a layer-list that will act as the background for the LinearLayoout.
>
> Add background_with_shadow.xml file to `res/drawable`. Containing:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item >
>         <shape 
>             android:shape="rectangle">
>         <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
>         <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
>         </shape>
>     </item>
>     <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
>         <shape 
>             android:shape="rectangle">
>         <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
>         <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
>         </shape>
>     </item>
> </layer-list>
> ```
>
> Then add the layer-list as background in your LinearLayout.
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>   android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"/>
> ```

You can also read: http://odedhb.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-layout-shadow-without-9-patch.html

- Another post from StackOverflow, [how to set shadow to a View in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406524/how-to-set-shadow-to-a-view-in-android), gives you another solution (using two views that form the shadow.):

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>     android:padding="10dp"
>     android:background="#CC55CC">
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>         <TableLayout
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:stretchColumns="0">
>             <TableRow>
>                 <LinearLayout
>                     android:id="@+id/content"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>                     <TextView  
>                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                         android:background="#FFFFFF" 
>                         android:text="@string/hello" />
>                 </LinearLayout>
>                 <View
>                     android:layout_width="5dp"
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>                     android:background="#55000000"/>
>             </TableRow>
>         </TableLayout>
>         <View
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="5dp"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
>             android:background="#55000000"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
> </FrameLayout>
> ```

- You can also use specific drawable form Android resources to mimic a shadow effect. Look at: [Android View shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211870/android-view-shadow) or just read a post below:

> I'm using Android Studio 0.8.6 and I couldn't find:
>
> ```
> android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"
> ```
>
> so I found this instead:
>
> ```
> android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
> ```
>
> and it looks like this:

[image: picture of a smartphone running Android, with the code example running]

---

If you're interested in clean Material Design effect, read some documentation like below:

- [Android L Developer Preview: Views and
  Shadows](http://wear.techbrood.com/preview/material/views-shadows.html)
- [Defining Shadows and Clipping
  Views](http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html)

Answer (score 84):

If you need to have shadow just on one side of the view (e.g. on top), you can add another View before it and use gradient shadow for its background.

Here is the gradient file `top_shadow_gradient.xml` that you have to store in `drawable` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#30ffffff"
        android:startColor="#40000000" />
</shape>
```

And here is a sample layout how to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_shadow_gradient" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">
        
        <!-- Put your content here-->
   
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Important:** The root layout have to be transparent (`android:background="@android:color/transparent"`) and your "content" layout need to have white background (`android:background="#ffffff"`).

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: The only solution that worked for me but I always get a stranger white line at begging of the shadow.

Comment: Setting endcolor to fully transparent black #0000 removed the white. However this strategy while easy, will not be a fully proper shadow like lighting creates

Comment: See [here](https://medium.com/@Zielony/clipping-and-shadows-on-android-e702a0d96bd4) for a pointer to how to do it with Paint.setXferemode()

Comment: What about corner radius?

Answer (score 5):

On hack I found for this is to wrap your view in a parent and use rotate. E.g. if you have a cardview and are adding elevation to it, you can put two rotates like this to achieve a shadow above instead of below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:rotation="180">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">
    <!--Card view content-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This gives something like the attached screenshot.

[image]

There's still a problem with this - this requires the paddingBottom to be set on the parent layout which means it'll be obvious that any scrollable sibling above the layout isn't going below it.

So even in today's age of elevation and outline provider, it's better to add a translucent view instead. :(

Comment: The other problem is that it turns any of the content inside the CardView upside down!

Comment: yea that'll require having the child also rotated 180. I know, bad.

Comment: its hacky way not the real solution.

Comment: totally. that's what I start out saying in my answer :)

Comment: as hacky as it is, this is unfortunately the best solution available.  Adding the shape has that awful white band and is considerably less elegant than this solution

Answer (score 5):

I have updated [Ivo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49877726/848353) excellent answer by including the use of ConstraintLayouts.

**Drawable**: shadow_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#40000000" android:endColor="#10ffffff" android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

**Layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/cl_topView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_bottomView"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
      
         ... nested views

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
      android:id="@+id/v_shadowTop"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="3dp"
      android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cl_bottomView"/>

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/cl_bottomView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_topView">

         ... nested views

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**
Following the steps above I was able to get the top shadow indicated by the arrow in the picture below.

[image]

**For those newer to Android Development:**

**Height Adjustment:**
The height of the shadow is controlled by the view's, "**v_shadowTop**", height (currently 3dp).

**Gradient Adjustment:**
The gradient's color is controlled by the last six characters (hex code) of the startColor (currently 000000) and endColor (currently ffffff) in the "**shadow_top.xml**" drawable.

The transparency is controlled by the first two characters of the startColor (currently 40) and endColor (currently 10) in the shadow_top.xml drawable.

Answer (score 3):

Top only Shadow:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <padding
            android:top="@dimen/_2sdp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/_8sdp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

if you want shadow to appear in other areas add padding `bottom`, `right`, `left`

Result:

[image: 1]

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Helped me to solve my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74136681/1545435