# How to achieve this shadow on top of a bottomsheet-like view

Tags: android

I need to add this shadow on top of my view like shown in theis Figma design:

[image]

I think I've tried everything:

- Using BottomSheetDialog and BottomSheetFragment were not useful as the background should be scrollable and I couldn't get this to be so. Apart from that couldn't add any sort of shadow/elevation via styling.
- Using a CardView as a container didn't help either because adding just normal elevation always shows on the bottom of a view - because in the world of Android the sun probably always shines from above. Strange concept to force upon a virtual design - meaning, why isn't it easily possible to determine a shadows direction??-
- Tried generating shadow drawable using [this suggestion](https://medium.com/@ArmanSo/take-control-of-views-shadow-android-c6b35ba573e9) but it's obviously not ment for a view like a bottom sheet which ONLY needs a shadow on top. The result looked like this: [image]

Should I ask my designer to generate shadow drawables like we did in the old days of web development before CSS could do anything?

PLEASE any direction would help!

Comment: I think you just need to increase the elevation.

Comment: Elevation in Android is always on the bottom. Not on the top as I need it here.

Comment: Elevation creates shadow all around the view, with bottom being the most prominent but not only there.

Comment: The shadow I need on top is the shadow I can only get on bottom using elevation which is very minor and thus negligible. I suggest you try that and see for yourself.
Anyway, found a way to do that. Refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after sitting on this for the most part of two days, and taking the time to finally post a question here about it, I suddenly [found the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68058039/1545435).

I just expanded it a bit with a double-edged gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Main top Shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:top="20dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="#20000000"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Secondary top Shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding
                android:top="8dp" />
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="#90000000"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="#000000" />
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
                android:topRightRadius="12dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The result:

[image]